# Delphi export to Excel - false errors in IDE for code that compiles

Tags: excel, delphi, range, cell

When coding for Excel in Delphi 10.3.3, I get false errors in the IDE for code that compiles and works just fine.

The error messages...

```
Undeclaired identifier 'Range' at line xxx
Undeclaired identifier 'Cells' at line xxx
```

...for every occurrence of the two excel variables.

Here's the complete code:

```
procedure tmainform.ExportToExcel;
var
  xls, wb, MyRange, CompletionRow: OLEVariant;
  arrData: Variant;
  ColCount, CurrRow, CurrCol: Integer;
begin
  ColCount:= 6;
  arrData:= VarArrayCreate([1, TotOrders+1, 1, ColCount], varVariant);

  for CurrCol:= 1 to ColCount do case currcol of
     1: arrData[1,1]:= 'ORDER#';
     2: arrData[1,2]:= 'DATE';
     3: arrData[1,3]:= 'ITEM';
     4: arrData[1,4]:= 'QTY';
     5: arrData[1,5]:= 'COST';
     6: arrData[1,6]:= 'RECEIVED?';
  end;

  for CurrRow:= 1 to TotOrders do begin
     for CurrCol:= 1 to ColCount do begin
        case currcol of
           1: arrData[CurrRow+1,1]:= Orders[1].Number;
           2: arrData[CurrRow+1,2]:= Orders[2].Date;
           3: arrData[CurrRow+1,3]:= Orders[3].Name;
           4: arrData[CurrRow+1,4]:= Orders[4].Qty;
           5: arrData[CurrRow+1,5]:= Orders[5].Cost;
           6: arrData[CurrRow+1,6]:= Orders[6].Received;
        end;
     end;
  end;

  xls:= CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  wb:= xls.Workbooks.Add;
{THIS LINE}  MyRange:= wb.WorkSheets[1].Range[wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[1, 1],wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[TotOrders+1, ColCount]];     // THIS LINE
  MyRange.Value:= arrData;
  MyRange.EntireColumn.Autofit;
{THIS LINE}  CompletionRow:= wb.WorkSheets[1].Range[wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[1, 1],wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[1, ColCount]];     // THIS LINE
  CompletionRow.font.bold := true;
{THIS LINE}  CompletionRow:= wb.WorkSheets[1].Range[wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[2, 5],wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[TotOrders+1, 5]];     // THIS LINE
  CompletionRow.NumberFormat:= '$#,##0.00';
  xls.Visible:= True;
  xls.ActiveWindow.Activate;
end;
```

Global variables are:

```
  Orders: array of ordertype;
  TotOrders: integer;
```

Again, this code runs and works just fine, but I'd like to get rid of those fake errors always showing in the upper left.

[image: fake errors - code compiles]

Comment: I doubt that those are "fake" errors, as you put it.  Which exact lines of your code snippet are lines 665, 668 and 670?

Comment: Firstly, your assuming that the downvote was mine.  Secondly, if you submit an inadequate question, omitting the correlation between line numbers and your code, which only you can know, what do you expect?

Comment: @MartynA I provided the errors and the code. Did you look for "Range" and "Cells" in the code I provided?

Comment: I have marked the start and end of the lines that generate the errors in the post.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug in Delphi. There is nothing you can do except upgrade to version "10.4 Sydney" (or later) [Reference](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/new-in-delphi-10-4-redesigned-code-insight/).

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @MartynA: I think fpiette is right. The OP's code compiles and runs just fine, but Error Insight in the IDE displays errors. This almost by definition makes the IDE's behaviour a bug. Also, my experience with 10.3 is that this was a *very* common issue and one of the things that have been improved in 10.4. (In fact, in my 10.3 IDE right now I have a project that is free from any errors and yet I have red squiggly lines everywhere and the list of error in the top-left part is really crowded with false positives.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Thanks, I wasn't doubting fpiette, for whom I have the greatest respect, just wondering if this particular problem was documented anywhere.

Comment: @MartynA: I think https://blogs.embarcadero.com/new-in-delphi-10-4-redesigned-code-insight/ is a decent source in this case.